# Javascript .innerHTML insertion requires two clicks to become viewable

Tags: javascript

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I'm making a very basic "translator" in Javascript, and I simply want to take user input, make a few changes with RegExp, then send back the modified information into an empty div.

When I click on the submit button, the information submits to the URL, removes itself from the input area, and flashes briefly in the desired area... but requires a second click to remain in #receptive as desired. I'm not sure if the effect I'm looking for requires AJAX.

```
<form name="translate" id="translate_frm" action="#">

Try it out: <input type="text" name="inputField" id="inputField" />

<button name="submit" onclick="processFormData();">Do it!</button>
</form>

<div id="receptive"></div>

<script>

function age(str) {
 return str.replace(/my/, "mine")
  .replace(/\bis\b/g, "be")
  .replace(/y\b/g, "ye")
  .replace(/t\b/g, "te")
  .replace(/t,/g, "te,")
  .replace(/t\./g, "te.");
}

function finalWrite(text, location) {
  document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = "<p>" + text + "</p>";
}

function processFormData() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputField");
  var refactored = age(inputText.value);
  finalWrite(refactored, "receptive");
}

</script>
```

Comment: No you would not need ajax to do this and as far as I can tell, without analyzing the regex you are using everything seems correct.  Is it possible that you are experiencing some lag in the calculations that make it look like it takes two clicks when really it's just taking extremely long for your browser to execute all the replace's?  Try using console.log (if you are using firebug or chrome) to monitor your function calls and watch what's going on as it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to cancel the form action by returning false when the button is clicked. You can check this to see if there is an extra request being sent using Firebug (or Chrome/IE developer tools).

```
function processFormData() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputField");
  var refactored = age(inputText.value);
  finalWrite(refactored, "receptive");
  return false;
}
```

See the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/W7nRW/  (note: the handler is being applied unobtrusively using jQuery.  If you remove the return statement from `processFormData`, you'll get an error about needing to use a POST request)